# My ActionMode doesn't inflates the menu in onCreateActionMode method

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

I'm trying display a menu-item in a ActionBar by ActionMode, but neither the ActionMode nor the menu-item aren't shown.

Making the LongClickListener of my ListView on the ProvasActivity.

```
    this.listView.setLongClickable(true);
    this.listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.d(null, "ListView Pressionado");

            // O action mode está ativado no momento?
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                // Cancela o evento
                return false;
            }
            selectedItem = position;

            mActionMode = ProvasActivity.this
                    .startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });

private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            // Infla o recurso do menu a ser exibido
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate( R.menu.linha_selecionada, menu );

            Log.d(null, "Menu Inflado");

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_remover:
                show();
                // Fecha a Action quando executada
                mode.finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Anula o ActionMode
            mActionMode = null;
            selectedItem = -1;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        private void show() {
            Toast.makeText(ProvasActivity.this,
                "show", Constants.TEMPO_TOAST).show();
            Log.d(null, "show()");
          }

    };
```

My menu for display the ActionMode item (layout/menu/linha_selecionada):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_remover"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/amazenadas"/>
</menu>
```

The view of my ProvasActivity (layout/provas_armazenadas.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="50dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying through of Vogella tutorial.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're returning `false` in `ActionMode.Callback.onCreateActionMode`.

[From the docs:](http://bit.ly/1gSJKX1)

> **Returns**
>
> true if the action mode should be created, false if entering this mode
> should be aborted